# Tags get pushed to the bottom in a result grid of the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

When running [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/236526/tags-that-can-be-cleared-of-votes) the tags get pushed to the bottom of their cells, as can be seen here:

[image]

This seems to be happening since [the latest update](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/557539801797505024) and is repro-ed in both IE and Chrome on Windows 7.

Can this be fixed please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gah, looks like this happened when I upgraded SlickGrid and I completely failed to notice.

To compound the issue, there was a refactoring fubarring that prevented the grid from getting larger rows when it contains tags. It still would have looked wonky even if that had been working, but at least they wouldn't have been truncated.

[Fixed now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/54), pending a pull and redeploy:

[image: updated slickgrid styling with tag results]

Note that there's still an issue where the width estimation calculation is fairly off for tag columns. Until I decide the best way to fix that just remember that the columns are at least resizable.